# proof of theorem deriving ch.f. from m.g.f.

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, reference-request

ch.f. = characteristic function

m.g.f. = moment generating function

THEOREM
Let $X$ be a random variable with $M_X(t) = E\left[e^{tX}\right]$ to exist and be finite for $\vert t\vert < \delta$ . Assume $\exists A(z)$ analytic in the region $\vert \operatorname{Re}(z)\vert < \delta^{\prime}$ , where $\delta^{\prime} > \delta > 0$ and $A(t) = M_X (t)$ for $t\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\vert t\vert <\delta$ , then : $$ \forall t\in\mathbb{R}~~\Big(\phi_X(t) = E\left[e^{itX}\right] = A(it)\Big)$$

Comment: Maybe a proof plan could be: 1) show that $\psi(z) = \mathbb{E}[e^{zX}]$ can be defined analytically  (Lebesgue dominated convergence) in the region $Re(z) < \delta$. 2) $\psi$ agrees with $M$ on the real line and $\phi$ on the imaginary line. 3) $\psi$ and $A$ agree because they are both analytic and agree on a segment. What have you tried to do on your own, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @Kore-N 2) is trivial . 3) As far a I understand this is called Identity theorem ( just to understand my level of knowledge , never heard it before) . Correct me if I am wrong : in 1) do you also use the following theorem :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations#Goursat.27s_theorem_and_its_generalizations